# Array given but validation fails

Tags: laravel

I have started to work again with Laravel(yey) and i have encountered this problem:

Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Validation\Factory::make() must be of the type array, none given

```
public function submit(Request $request){

    if ($request->input('choice') == "1"){
        $validation = 'required|min:3|exists:accounts,alias';
    }
    else {
        $validation = 'required|email|exists::accounts,email';
    }

    $this->validate($request, Validator::make(array('field' => $request->input('field')), array('field' => $validation)));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are doing it slightly wrong. I suggest you read through the validation chapter of the docs one more time.

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation

However, I think this might solve your problem:

```
public function submit(Request $request){

    if ($request->input('choice') == "1"){
        $validation = 'required|min:3|exists:accounts,alias';
    }
    else {
        $validation = 'required|email|exists::accounts,email';
    }

    // Make sure the 'field' is set to whatever <input name="field_name"> you got
    $this->validate($request, array('field' => $validation));
}
```